# Batch scripting.. i want to run a command automatically based upon user input

Tags: batch-file, cmd, return-value, user-input, external-process

writing a script so that when a certain value is returned it opens cmd. Then using a value that the user has added automatically run a command in cmd. not sure if this is even possible or not but any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Edited - the code before

```
:OpekaiNetReset
echo "Target IP; host is DOWN!"
echo Enter your target IP
set/p TargetIP="Enter your target IP"
ping %TargetIP%
IF %TargetIP%==packets recieved +1 start cmd.exe
IF %TargetIp%==packets recieved 0 goto OpekaiNetReset
:OpekaiCMD
cls
echo "Target IP; host is UP!"
```

Comment: Edit your question and post what did you tried as code until now !

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a wing at things, not being sure exactly what you want -- I commented out a few of your lines via **::**  and added replacements.  The below should at least tell you if a host is up/down based on received packets from ping.  Unsure what you meant by running cmd.exe on a certain count?  The below runs command if the received packet count is 1.

```
:OpekaiNetReset
echo "Target IP; host is DOWN!"
::echo Enter your target IP
set/p TargetIP="Enter your target IP: "

::ping %TargetIP%
set received=0
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%p in ('ping %TargetIP%^|find /i "received"') do set /a %%p
echo packets received == %received%
::IF %TargetIP%==packets recieved +1 start cmd.exe
if %received%==1 start cmd.exe & exit /b
::IF %TargetIp%==packets recieved 0 goto OpekaiNetReset
if %received%==0 goto OpekaiNetReset

:OpekaiCMD
cls
echo "Target IP; host is UP!"
```

Comment: Thank you im pretty new to it all and writing up on my mobile so havent actually ran it as im away from my laptop. i will note that as its more or less what i was after but what i intended to do was to automatically open cmd if packets were recieved back, if not then nothing happens, but continue to automatically run commands in cmd afterwards